# Csv upolading failed in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I am trying to upload bulk data using csv upload.File uploading done perfectly but data fetching form csv fails and shows the below error

**array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class '100' not found**
This is my code in my controller

```
if ( isset($_FILES["userfile"])) 
        {               
            $this->load->library('upload_photo');

            //Set the config
            $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/uploads/csv/'; 
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv'; 
            $config['max_size'] = '200';
            $config['overwrite'] = TRUE; 

            $this->upload_photo->initialize($config);

            if( ! $this->upload_photo->do_upload())
            {
                $error = $this->upload_photo->display_errors();

            } 

            //If the upload success
            $csv = $this->upload_photo->file_name;                  
            $arrResult = array();
            $handle = fopen("assets/uploads/csv/".$csv, "r");
            if( $handle )
            {
                    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
                    {
                    $arrResult[] = $row;
                    }
            fclose($handle);
            }
            $titles = array_shift($arrResult);              
            $keys = array('id', 'name', 'city','state');        
            $final = array();

            foreach ( $arrResult as $key => $value )
             {
              $final[] = array_combine($keys, $value);
             }
            $rw=2;
            foreach($final as $csv_em)
             {                  
                $rw++;  
                $id[] = $csv_em['id'];
                $name[] = $csv_em['name'];                  
                $city[] = $csv_em['city'];
                $state[] = $csv_em['state'];

            }

        }
        $ikeys = array('id', 'name', 'city','state');
        $items = array();
        foreach ( array_map($id, $name, $city, $state) as $ikey => $value)
        {
            $items[] = array_combine($ikeys, $value);
        }   

        $this->employee_model->insertByCSV($items);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach ( array_map($id, $name, $city, $state) as $ikey => $value)
    {
        $items[] = array_combine($ikeys, $value);
    }
```

try this

```
foreach ( array_map(function($a,$b,$c,$d){return array($a,$b,$c,$d);},$id, $name, $city, $state) as $ikey => $value)
    {
        $items[] = array_combine($ikeys, $value);
    }
```

as the infomation said ,you need to give a callback function as array_map first parameter